# Attempt to install node.js on OS X fails but I can't find support

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Sorry if this is more detailed than anyone needs but I don't know stackoverflow well so I'm erring on the side of more info is better.

I'm really interested in exploring Amber, so I began to follow the online instructions in an article by Richard Eng [here][1]. Step 1 is to install node.js, so I went to the link in his piece at https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories but I was unable to find any information I could understand and use on that site so I searched for "install node.js os x" and ended up at this [page][2].

Following the instructions on that page (already had XCode installed), I downloaded and installed Homebrew, then followed the instructions in the Terminal. Things *seemed* to run fine but when I did the suggested npm -v command in the console, I got a not found error.

I searched for help installing with Homebrew and got to this [page][3]. It indicated there were in fact some issues and provided a way around it. So I selected those lines and pasted them into the terminal. The final line of that instruction list -- curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh -- whirred and clicked for a while and then displayed in the terminal:

```
sh: rimraf: command not found
/Users/dan/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/dan/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/q5/qng_fj592vscw92h8mv01j480000gn/T/npm.52096/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0
npm ERR! path ../../../../../../private/var/folders/q5/qng_fj592vscw92h8mv01j480000gn/T/npm.52096/package/man/man7/npm-developers.7
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, symlink '../../../../../../private/var/folders/q5/qng_fj592vscw92h8mv01j480000gn/T/npm.52096/package/man/man7/npm-developers.7' -> '/Users/dan/.npm-packages/share/man/man7/npm-developers.7'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, symlink '../../../../../../private/var/folders/q5/qng_fj592vscw92h8mv01j480000gn/T/npm.52096/package/man/man7/npm-developers.7' -> '/Users/dan/.npm-packages/share/man/man7/npm-developers.7'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dan/.npm/_logs/2017-03-06T20_57_44_069Z-debug.log
It failed
(23) Failed writing body
```

I grabbed that log file but I'm darned if I can figure out where to send it or make a support request.

Can anyone help? I'm bound and determined to get Amber working regardless of what it takes.

Thanks for helping out an old-timer!

Dan

Comment: Make sure to add `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH`, http://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0.pkg

Comment: you can try to use `brew` to install node

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Locating that file did the trick. I now have node and npm installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple fix for those who installed `node` via Homebrew without `npm` and later on struggled with `npm` installation using an official script. This approach assumes you have run the `node` installation as follows:

```
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

If above failed then start from here. Remove `npm` if any:

```
rm -rf ~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Download and unpack the latest version of `npm`:

```
cd ~
curl -L https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.6.0.tgz | tar xz
```

Move unpacked package into node_modules folder:

```
mv ~/package ~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Add following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export NPM_PACKAGES="$HOME/.npm-packages"
export NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
export PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
```

Source the file:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Verify installation:

```
npm -v
```